# Pressing Win+X, Alt-Tab programmatically

Tags: c++, windows-8, keyboard, sendinput

I'm trying to simulate the keypress events for Win+X on Windows 8 which should pop up a small menu, but I have been unable to get this to work by using SendInput. For any other combination of keys (e.g. Win+R, Win+E, Win+D) it works but not for Win+X. I've noticed that Synergy+ has the same problem, but the Windows on-screen keyboard doesn't. I have also looked at the parameters for SendInput that the on-screen keyboard uses but if I use exactly the same parameters in my application I still don't get the menu.

So my question, how do I get this to work? Or is there an alternative way to display this menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently added support for this to our application. Glad we beat our competitor to it!

There are new UIPI restrictions in Windows 8. The most-used blocked shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so you're going to want to do the workaround.

You have to mark your binaries with `uiAccess="true"` in the manifest. (For more detail on how to do this, google.) This manifest prevents binaries from being launched unless signed with a Microsoft-approved code signing certificate and installed in a "secure location" (system32 or Program Files/Program Files (x86)).

If you lanch your program from any helpers: The uiAccess binary can't be launched with `CreateProcess` from a medium integrity process (the manifest marks it as requiring "high" integrity). Instead, it's easiest to launch it using `ShellExecute` "open" to get the shell to elevate it. If using `CreateProcessAsUser`, you have to set `TokenUIAccess` to 1 using `SetTokenInformation`, or launching will fail.

Final provisos: note that uiAccess quite heavily restricts what a process can do. You can't receive UI input from normal (medium integrity) processes, so other applications can't interact with your windows. If you don't already follow good practices in separating your UI into a separate process, this would therefore be a good reason to do that. Alternatively, the tasks requiring uiAccess could be put into a small, self-contained helper binary and entirely separated from the non-UI process too. Your main app can run it as a high-integrity helper process that is sent instructions as required to perform those specific tasks (such as `SendInput`).

Finally, `SendInput` will work.

Comment: Now your competitors get a heads up here. :-)

Comment: I doubt anyone would change programs just because of this... ;)

Comment: Be aware that uiAccess = true might prevent drag&drop from other programs with less privileges.

Comment: Another addition here. You can start a uiAccess process with CreateProcessAsUser from a service, but you have to set TokenUIAccess to 1 using SetTokenInformation first.

Comment: @Maurice Excellent correction! I tried all sorts of tricks to launch a uiAccess program cross-session, and couldn't find out how, though given our process structure it wasn't needed. Thanks! I'll fix the answer.